# A problem from a mathematical olympiad

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> John chose $100$ distinct positive integers and wrote all the $4950$ pairwise sums. How many of them could be exact powers of $3$?

I tried to look at it in $\mod 3$ and $\mod 9$. When there are $4$ numbers the answer is $3$. I have an example for $99$ and no other ideas.

Comment: from which olympiad do you get this Problem?

Comment: Do the 100 positive integers have to be distinct ? If not, 50 1s and 50 2s give 2500 sums equal to 3 (the rest are 2s and 4s).

Comment: it is from problemsheet for 8th graders in St. Petersburg.

Comment: @gandalf61 Sorry, they do

Comment: What have you tried yourself? You should add that to the question to avoid downvotes and closure.

Comment: @drhab Done. Added to the problem.

Comment: Are the integers consecutive?

Comment: @MainakRoy Of course not necessarily

Comment: Fuzzy idea:  Write the 100 numbers in base 3.  If two of them add to a power of three, then the base 3 expansion is $100\ldots 0$. It seems like this considerations eliminates a lot of possibilities.